# How do I stop Google indexing my main page as https

Tags: google, redirects, https, seo, google-search-console

Due to historic reasons, we have things set up so that `"www.mydomain.com"` redirects to `"store.mydomain.com".`

This has worked perfectly fine until recently, when Google appears to be sending visitors to `"https:// www.mydomain.com"` which doesn't have an SSL-certificate (and never has). Strangely, its only the first link that goes to `"https:// www.mydomain.com"`, all other links point correctly to `"http:// store.mydomain.com".`

Because there is no certificate on the **"www"** version, users are getting an error message.

How do I make Google revert to pointing the main link at `"http:// store.mydomain.com"` (or even `"http:// www.mydomain.com."`)

If I remove `"https:// www.mydomain.com"` from Google webmaster tools, will this also remove the redirected page (`"http:// store.mydomain.com`)?

Thanks.

Comment: In your hosting account can you serve https versions of your URL with a .htaccess redirect? 
Sorry if this sounds obvious you never know who you are dealing with on forums

Comment: Thanks, but the security certificate error happens _before_ the redirect is sent from the server so this didn't work (there was already a 301-redirect in place).

Comment: The workaround for this was purchasing a wildcard certificate and then using that (we couldn't use multiple certificates as www. and store. resolved to the same IP address). Google still points to https:// www. but at least it now redirects without any error messages.